# search through multiple categories

Tags: wordpress

I like to search the word through unique multiple categories.

I prepared this code.

```
<form role="search" class="cat-search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">

<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="cat" id="cat0" /><label for="cat0">all categories</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="cat" id="cat1" /><label for="cat1">category 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="cat" id="cat2" /><label for="cat2">category 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="cat" id="cat3" /><label for="cat2">category 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="cat" id="cat4" /><label for="cat2">category 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="cat" id="cat5" /><label for="cat2">category 5</label>  

<input name="s" size="25" type="text" placeholder="search after select categories" />
<input type="submit" class="cat-search" value="search" />

</form>
```

When I try to search "word" with categories 1 and 2, url is becoming like this.

/?cat=1&cat=2&s=word

Is there any way to change it to this url?

/?cat=1,2&s=words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Comes handy with these,

remove name attributes on all those checkboxes and add hidden input for cat, then populate its value based on checkboxes

```
<form role="search" class="cat-search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="cat0" class="cats"/><label for="cat0">all categories</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="cat1" class="cats"/><label for="cat1">category 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="cat2" class="cats"/><label for="cat2">category 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="cat3" class="cats"/><label for="cat3">category 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="cat4" class="cats"/><label for="cat4">category 4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="5" id="cat5" class="cats"/><label for="cat5">category 5</label>  
    <input type="hidden" id="cat" name="cat" />
    <input name="s" size="25" type="text" placeholder="search after select categories" />
    <input type="submit" class="cat-search" value="search" />

</form>
```

Then your jQuery to assign value to hidden inputs when checkboxes are click

```
$('body').on('click', '.cats', function() {
    var cats = $('.cats:checked').map( function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
    $('#cat').val( cats );
});
```

Just a note, the comma (,) in the url will be encoded and would look something like

```
yoursite.com/?cat=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4&s=bah
```

although this shouldn't matter if you're processing the value on php